# table of anova results in rmarkdown - p-value column is missing

Tags: r, html-table, r-markdown, anova, kable

I was performing several ANOVA. Now I want to illustrate the output tables in rmarkdown.
I used the `kable` function for this, like I did for other tables before.

This is the anova result in the console:

```
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                                  Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value   Pr(>F)   
as.factor(mzp)                    19.838   6.613     3 708.87  0.5298 0.661942   
as.factor(Gruppe)                119.667 119.667     1 314.45  9.5879 0.002135 **
as.factor(mzp):as.factor(Gruppe)  24.781   8.260     3 708.87  0.6618 0.575717   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

My code for the html table in rmarkdown is:

```
m1 <- lmer(IS ~ as.factor(mzp)*as.factor(Gruppe)+(1|id),data = df1, na.action = "na.omit")
anova.m1 <- anova(m1)
```

```
anova.m1 %>% 
  kable() %>% 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped"))
```

But in the rmarkdown table the column for the p-value is missing (and also the `DenDF` column)

[image]

I have no clue why this is happening and couldn't find anything about it.

EDIT:

This is the output for `dput(anova.m1)`

> 

```
dput(anova.m1)
structure(list(`Sum Sq` = c(19.8375584010659, 119.667438141421, 
24.7805685386945), `Mean Sq` = c(6.61251946702196, 119.667438141421, 
8.26018951289818), NumDF = c(3L, 1L, 3L), DenDF = c(708.866106013766, 
314.450622864359, 708.866106009366), `F value` = c(0.529805679182321, 
9.58794732578341, 0.661819649360765), `Pr(>F)` = c(0.661941822921109, 
0.00213497982537724, 0.575717330685176)), row.names = c("as.factor(mzp)", 
"as.factor(Gruppe)", "as.factor(mzp):as.factor(Gruppe)"), class = c("anova", 
"data.frame"), heading = "Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method", hypotheses = list(
    `as.factor(mzp)` = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5), .Dim = c(3L, 
    8L), .Dimnames = list(c("as.factor(mzp)t2", "as.factor(mzp)t3", 
    "as.factor(mzp)t4"), c("(Intercept)", "as.factor(mzp)t2", 
    "as.factor(mzp)t3", "as.factor(mzp)t4", "as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse", 
    "as.factor(mzp)t2:as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse", "as.factor(mzp)t3:as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse", 
    "as.factor(mzp)t4:as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse"))), `as.factor(Gruppe)` = structure(c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25), .Dim = c(1L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(
        "as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse", c("(Intercept)", "as.factor(mzp)t2", 
        "as.factor(mzp)t3", "as.factor(mzp)t4", "as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse", 
        "as.factor(mzp)t2:as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse", "as.factor(mzp)t3:as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse", 
        "as.factor(mzp)t4:as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse"))), `as.factor(mzp):as.factor(Gruppe)` = structure(c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1), .Dim = c(3L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("as.factor(mzp)t2:as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse", 
    "as.factor(mzp)t3:as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse", "as.factor(mzp)t4:as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse"
    ), c("(Intercept)", "as.factor(mzp)t2", "as.factor(mzp)t3", 
    "as.factor(mzp)t4", "as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse", "as.factor(mzp)t2:as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse", 
    "as.factor(mzp)t3:as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse", "as.factor(mzp)t4:as.factor(Gruppe)Sportklasse"
    )))))
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Could you please provide us the output for `dput(anova.m1)`?

Comment: I just tested this and it works fine on my site?

Comment: it works on my machine.. have set any global options for knitr?

Comment: I didn't changed anything in the global options. I added the output for dput(anova.m1) in my question. Thanks!

Comment: Worked fine with me