# R function for displaying results of aov() and tukeyHSD() in R markdown in professional way

Tags: r, r-markdown, anova, tukey

I have some data that's unfortunately PHI and I can't share (to make reproducible) but I'd like to display it in a PDF document from R markdown.

Currently my results will display, but they don't look great, i.e.:
[image]
[image]

I'd love to display the exact same numbers, but just "prettier".  No "##" along the side, and just a nice table in R markdown

I've obviously googled it, and I ran across sites such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66634901/table-of-anova-results-in-rmarkdown-p-value-column-is-missing) or [this one](https://rdrr.io/github/aphanotus/borealis/man/rmd.anova.table.html)

But there seems to be drawbacks to using many of these methods.  Either it uses a different code to initially conduct the anova (I used aov(), some of these sites use lm() and it doesn't seem to work with aov()  ), or it doesn't help with the Tukey results.... or when I load the package it hides an important function I need in a different package  (library(papeR) masks summarise, and summarize from dplyr() ).

Is there a simply way I'm missing in order to display those results 'cleanly'?

Comment: `huxtable` or `gt` can both write pretty PDF tables and give you control over formatting. `modelsummary` is also a powerful tool which can use either of these as a backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how professionals format these things, but I think, the nicest solution is **`broom` + `any table package`**.

**For example:**

````
```{r warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(broom)
library(flextable)

fm1 <- aov(breaks ~ wool + tension, data = warpbreaks)
thsd <- TukeyHSD(fm1, "tension", ordered = TRUE)
xx <- tidy(thsd)

flextable(xx)
```
````

[image]

Looks nice, I think.